# Android N - how to check if apk is signed with schema v2

Tags: android, apk, signature, android-signing

Android N provided [new apk Signature Scheme v2](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#apk_signature_v2),
how can I check if a specific apk is signed with that new signature?

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- Run `apksigner verify -v <apk>` and look for `Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true` in the output. apksigner can be found in Android SDK build tools 24.0.3. apksigner's source code is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/.
- For an already installed package on Android Nougat: `adb shell pm dump <package name> | grep apkSigningVersion`. `1` means conventional JAR signing scheme, `2` means APK Signature Scheme v2.
- You can also run `grep 'APK Sig Block 42' app.apk` but this may have false positives. Only if there is no match is it certain that the APK is not signed using APK Signature Scheme v2.

EDIT: Added information about apksigner which wasn't yet available when the original answer was written.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm first 2 methods are working fine (app targeting android 11)

Comment: confirming also .. the first one works great for me