# Add APK Signature Scheme v2 in gradle for ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

Google Play reject my react native app with error:

`ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): No APK Signature Scheme v2 signature from this signer ERROR (APK Signature Scheme v2 signer #0): No JAR signature from this signer.`

It's look like a need to sign my app with v2 scheme but offical site have only manual for v1 scheme (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) and it's not enough for google play.

How can I sign my react native app with v2 scheme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have something similar in your gradle file if you followed the guide of ReactNative or the official Android guide.

[image]

In this way, when you run the command

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The APK will include both types of signing.

The important part is to add `v2SigningEnabled true` to the signing config.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add `v2SigningEnabled` because it should be signed with v2 by default from Android Studio 2.2 and Gradle 2.2 onwards.

> By default, Android Studio 2.2 and the Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2 sign your app using both APK Signature Scheme v2 and the traditional signing scheme, which uses JAR signing.

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2

You can check if your apk is already signed using the android apksigner build tool. On mac the command is something like:

```
❯ ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.1/apksigner verify -v 1594191166.apk
```

For more info about checking if an apk is signed refer to this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957522/android-n-how-to-check-if-apk-is-signed-with-schema-v2).